# How to split a table column using split-array

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently looking for a way to split a database to send messages after 60 minutes or so. I have a table with over 1000 rows being returned from the database and would like to split them into groups of 50. I would appreciate an example of how this can be attained. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script that is navigated to like the following:

`runner.php?start=0&limit=50`

This page would start at row 0 and do 50 repeats. Then after 50 repeats it would echo out:

```
<script>setTimeout(function() {
    window.location='runner.php?start=50&limit=50';
}, 3600000)</script>
```

Where `start=50` would be the `$_GET['start'] + $_GET['limit']`

You would need to keep your browser window opened though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk`:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($results, 50);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        sleep(3600); // Pause an hour except at the beginning
    }
    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        // Do what you want with the row
    }
}
```

Don't do this on a web page, as the browser will time out waiting for the results. But you can do it in a CLI script.